# stop Audio recording on user prompt using dsp.AudioRecorder?

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I'm new to matlab. I'm using the following code to record the sound from micro on a wav file:

```
AR = dsp.AudioRecorder('OutputNumOverrunSamples',true);
audiofile='test.wav';
nbsec=10;
AFW = dsp.AudioFileWriter(audiofile,'FileFormat', 'WAV');
disp('Recording starts now');
tic;
while toc < nbsec,
   [audioIn,nOverrun] = step(AR);
   [x, indexMax] = max(abs(fft(audioIn(:,1)-mean(audioIn(:,1)))));
  step(AFW,audioIn);
  if nOverrun > 0
    fprintf('Audio recorder queue was overrun by %d samples\n',nOverrun);
  end
end
release(AR);
release(AFW);
disp('Recording done!');
```

It works, but the problem is I don't know in advance for how long I should be recording so rather than using a time constraint (with tic toc), I would like to be able to finish the recording by pressing the 'f' button. But I have no idea how to implement this in matlab.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Audio Recorder Object](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiorecorder.html). This has a method which records without blocking the controls. While this is running you can check for your keypress and use the stop method when it is detected

Comment: This is a good solution but that audio recorder object only works for 1 or 2 channels.  Do you know of a solution that works with dsp.AudioRecorder for more than 2 channels?

Comment: i can not try, since i have no input dev with more then 2 channels, but the matlab recorder object seems like it has  no checks for something like channels < 2, have you tried? if not, can you use 2 or more recorder objects to capture the seperate channels? maybe by defining virtual sound devs for the seperate channels?